# Android Room - Select query with LIKE

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm trying to make a query to search all objects whose names contain text:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM hamster WHERE name LIKE %:arg0%")
fun loadHamsters(search: String?): Flowable<List<Hamster>>
```

Messages:

```
Error:no viable alternative at input 'SELECT * FROM hamster WHERE name LIKE %'
Error:There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "%": syntax error)
Error:Unused parameter: arg0
```

Also, I'm trying:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM hamster WHERE name LIKE '%:arg0%'")
fun loadHamsters(search: String?): Flowable<List<Hamster>>
```

Messages:

```
Error:Unused parameter: arg0
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

You should enclose the `%` characters in your input query - not in the query itself.

E.g. try this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM hamster WHERE name LIKE :arg0")
fun loadHamsters(search: String?): Flowable<List<Hamster>>
```

Then your `String search` value should look like:

```
search = "%fido%";
loadHamsters(search);
```

Furthermore, the binding parameter name should match the variable name, so rather than `arg0` it should look like:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM hamster WHERE name LIKE :search")
fun loadHamsters(search: String?): Flowable<List<Hamster>>
```

Comment: Note that there is currently a bug with parameter names in Kotlin's annotation processing: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17959

Comment: @KirillRakhman but this method still works fine ;-)  
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44448566/6674369

Comment: @AndriyAntonov the Kotlin bug was fixed 9 months ago

Answer (score 480):

You can just concat using SQLite string concatenation.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM hamster WHERE name LIKE '%' || :search || '%'")
fun loadHamsters(search: String?): Flowable<List<Hamster>>
```

Comment: work even with kotlin bug: youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17959

Comment: This approach is actually what the question was asking for. Although the other answer is quite good too.

Comment: I understand the `'%'` but can someone explain what is `'||'` and why?

Comment: `||` is string concatenate operator. Think of it as `+` in Java String.

Comment: @SanlokLee But in answer, '%' is char type not string. Why it doesn't throw an error when concatenating string with char?

Comment: @RohitSawai, the query expression is in SQLite. SQLite uses single quotation marks to represent string literals.

Comment: @SanlokLee You didn't understand my question. We pass String value to Query annotation. But in that passed query, we wanna pass % as we need in Like operation but we have quoted % sign in single quote instead of double and have used unfamiliar || pipe operators as well. My question is why we used single quote instead of double around % operator?

Comment: I am sorry if my prev answer wasn't clear enough but I will just have to repeat my last sentence: **SQLite uses single quotation marks to represent string literals.** You wrote "_We pass String value to Query annotation_", and the String you mentioned represents an SQLite statement. You don't use double quotes here because the _content_ of the string is supposed to be an SQLite statement, not Java nor Kotlin syntax.

Comment: this is kotlin, so **for java** should it be like this:  `@Query("SELECT * FROM CarSales where vechno like :vechno1 ORDER BY vechno")
    public abstract List<Cars> searchVehno(String vechno1); //**add % in the vaue passed as-> vehno1+"%" in function call**`

Comment: @AndroidLearner No, even in Java you don't have to pre-concatenate the `'%'` before passing the parameter to the query — the syntax of the query described in this answer is SQLite syntax, and it doesn't matter if you use Kotlin or Java to define the DAO with that query. In your case, `@Query("SELECT * FROM CarSales WHERE vechno LIKE :vechno || '%' ORDER BY vechno") public abstract List<Cars> searchVehno(String vechno);` should work just as well without any problems.

Answer (score 55):

Some Examples of **LIKE** Keywords used in dao with Room Database.

1. Start with **Search_Query**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM hamster WHERE name LIKE :search_query || '%'")
    fun loadHamsters(search_query: String?): Flowable<List<Hamster>>
```

2. End with **Search_Query**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM hamster WHERE name LIKE '%' || :search_query ")
   fun loadHamsters(search_query: String?): Flowable<List<Hamster>>
```

3. Get all that have **Search_Query**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM hamster WHERE name LIKE '%' || :search_query || '%'")
   fun loadHamsters(search_query: String?): Flowable<List<Hamster>>
```

4. Use NOT LIKE For except data which have **Search_Query**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM hamster WHERE name NOT LIKE '%' || :search_query || '%'")
   fun loadHamsters(search_query: String?): Flowable<List<Hamster>>
```

Comment: || help us concat the string, so '%' || 'abc' || '%' == '%abc%'.

Answer (score 1):

Room only supports named bind parameter **:name** to avoid any confusion between the method parameters and the query bind parameters.

Room will automatically bind the parameters of the method into the bind arguments. This is done by matching the name of the parameters to the name of the bind arguments.

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name LIKE :name AND last_name LIKE :last")
 public abstract List<User> findUsersByNameAndLastName(String name, String last);
```