# Android Rooms - Search in String

Tags: android, sql, android-room, android-architecture-components

In the Android Rooms persistence library, how would I write the following SQL statement as a @Query?

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE %:value%`

This syntax is invalid, and I can't find anything about it in the documentation.

Comment: Make sure your table name is not table itself :)

Comment: @Spiderman I'm talking about the new Rooms persistence library. I know how to write it in regular sql :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Room - Select query with LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184769/android-room-select-query-with-like)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can just concatenate using SQLite string concatenation.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%' || :value  || '%'")
```

Comment: what if I want the `field` starts with `:value`?
Thank you :)

Comment: @AhmedMostafa @Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE :value  || '%'")

Answer (score 4):

[The answer by yigit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234644/android-rooms-search-in-string/44448576#44448576) works great for me:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM stores " +
        "WHERE name LIKE '%' || :search  || '%' " +
        "OR description LIKE '%' || :search  || '%'")
```