# Room Persistence Library

Tags: android, android-room

I'm new using Android room persistence library, usually, I use the DBHeper for managing the data, but I'm trying to use this technology, I wanna know how can I use this query at Room persistence library

```
SELECT * FROM CLIENTS where name LIKE %name%
```

But when I use % after "Like" I Android underline this on red line

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184769/android-room-select-query-with-like

Comment: A lot of thank you Mr.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter like in example below:

```
@Dao
public interface MyDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE age > :minAge")
public User[] loadAllUsersOlderThan(int minAge);

}
```

or if you want to pass a collection :

```
@Dao
public interface MyDao {

@Query("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM user WHERE region IN (:regions)")
public List<NameTuple> loadUsersFromRegions(List<String> regions);
}
```