# In room persistent library not able to use like clause

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am using room persistent library in my project. I am trying to use 'like' clause in query but I am not able to use. I have tried both compile time (Query) and run time query (Raw Query ). Neither it's giving any kind of exception nor it's giving any output.

I have tried following ways but none of them worked :-

1. Compile time Query -

   ```
   @Query("select * from recipe where type_of_diet like '%vegetarian%' ")
   public abstract DataSource.Factory<Integer, RecipeListPojo> 
   getRecipeListVeg();
   ```
2. RawQuery -

   ```
   @RawQuery(observedEntities = RecipeListPojo.class)
   public abstract DataSource.Factory<Integer,RecipeListPojo> 
   getAllRecipesList(SupportSQLiteQuery sqLiteQuery);

   String query="select * from recipe  where type_of_diet like '%vegetarian%' ";
   SimpleSQLiteQuery simpleSQLiteQuery = new SimpleSQLiteQuery(query);
   recipeDao.getAllRecipesList(simpleSQLiteQuery);
   ```

compileSdkVersion 27

Library used -
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0-beta3"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.0-beta3"

Kindly let me know how can I run these type of queries.

Answer (score 5):

Room 1.1.1 + RxJava2 + Kotlin it is working fine:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE '%Tom%' ")
fun getUsers(): Single<List<UserEntity>>
```

With parameter:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE '%' || :name || '%' ")
fun getUsers(name: String): Single<List<UserEntity>>
```

Comment: This works. Can you tell me how can we pass List<String> and check if any of them is present instead of searching 1 name.

Answer (score 1):

You have to append before the symbol `"%"` as a prefix and postfix of your string to perform a patterned search, for example:

```
String param = "%"+mMyString+"%";
```

Then declare your DAO method, for example:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM track_table WHERE title LIKE :param" + " OR artist LIKE :param" + " OR album like :param")
List< Track > search(String param);
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is not correct for your query. As per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Query), query would be similar to

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name LIKE :name AND last_name LIKE :last")
public abstract List<User> findUsersByNameAndLastName(String name, String last);
```

Here `arguments` and `key written with LIKE :` must match.

---

Read [Android Room - Select query with LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184769/android-room-select-query-with-like), which in kotlin but may clear this logic.

Comment: What if i don't want to compare it with some arguments , and i want to use some static value, like as I did in my example