# Android Room Query: Text Matches Exactly the Search String or Start With Search String

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-room

What would be the android room query to match a column data exactly match or start with the search string

VVV this seems to giving me only the exact match

`select * from table where dna_sequence like :searchTerm`

Thanks

Comment: I think it reference to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184769/android-room-select-query-with-like. You can check it.

Comment: I've written an answer below. If you need more help, we need to see your Entity and DAO classes. The problem is in your Java or Kotlin code and the value being passed to `searchTerm`. The SQL query is exactly correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this seems to giving me only the exact match
>
> ```
> select * from table where dna_sequence like :searchTerm
> ```

There is nothing wrong with your query. The problem is with your Java or Kotlin code. You are getting an exact match because you are passing an exact to `searchTerm` and not using any wildcards. The `LIKE` operator in SQL allows us to use wildcards in the string to match more than just strict equality. `_` will match a single character while `%` will match zero or more characters. If you don't use these wildcards, then `LIKE` will be the exact same as `=`. So you need to pass a value for `searchTerm` that uses one of these wild card characters. For example, if you a DAO interface declared as

```
@Dao
public interface MyDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE search like :searchTerm")
    public Foo[] getFooSearch(String searchTerm);
}
```

You can call the method with something like:

```
MyDao dao;
dao.getFooSearch("abcdef%");
```

which will match the start of the string.

Note: This example is a bit contrived because you only provided your SQL query and didn't provide any of the Java or Kotlin code for your DAO or Data Entity.

Comment: Thanks it makes sense now

Answer (score 2):

Try this in search method:

```
public String getResultForSearchString(String searchTerm){
String searchExptression=searchTerm+"%";
//.. perform search operation on SQLite with searchExpression
return result;
}
```

For more information visit: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-like/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer