# Android Room: SQLite query "WHERE ... LIKE .. " always returns empty list

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have a simple SQLite query that should allow the user to search for beers based on name:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM beers WHERE beer_name LIKE '%' + :searchString + '%'")
    fun searchBeer(searchString: String): Flow<List<Beer>>
```

But the list is always empty. Does anyone know why?
I tested a similar query online like this:
[image]

If I remove the WHERE clause, I get a full list of beers returned.
I am farily certain I am messing up in the query syntax. But not 100%.

EDIT: Leaving this one open, but answer is found here:
[Android Room - Select query with LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184769/android-room-select-query-with-like)

Comment: That sort of double-wildcard query is going to be slow for larger tables. You might want to consider adding in Room full-text search support (e.g., `@Fts4`) if you expect to do this sort of search a lot. Beyond that, you might want to try other intermediate query forms between "no `WHERE` clause" and "`LIKE` with double wildcards". For example, does `LIKE` work with a single trailing `%`, or where the `%` is in the `searchString` value itself (rather than being in the query)?

Comment: SQLite's concatenation operator is `||` and not `+`.